# SVN get code changes in log

Tags: svn

When using log (or some other svn command), is there some way to see exactly what changed in the code? I know --verbose will get the files, but I was hoping I could see exactly what lines had been added or removed w/ each change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `svn diff`.

Comment: Using the "-c revision-number" argument would give the change for a specific repository version.